# Two Date Fields, One Date Filter

Tags: cognos

Depending on a condition, `[Example] = 'Business'`, I want to filter by `[Date A]` or `[Date B]`

I have written out a statement like such from the query page in the filter section but am getting a error. I plan to ad x_date as the parameter to a prompt page but can't seem to get this to work. I guess I can create two separate reports and `UNION` them but i'm sure there is a way to knock this out with a conditional formula.

```
if ( [Example] = 'Business') then
    [Date A] in_range ?x_date?
else
    [Date B] in_range ?x_date?
```

Any idea how I can apply a single date filter to conditionally apply to to the target date columns?

[image]

Comment: I tried using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32015664/6706419) but it still gives error.

Comment: When I create two separate queries that are unioned with individual `in_range` parameters I get no error on the individual filter but when I try to add this parameter to a date prompt the parameter does not show up as a selectable option. LOL triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion

Create a data item called [target date] in your query
With the expression

```
IF([Example] = 'Business')Then([Date A])Else([Date B])
```

Then add the filter for your query

```
[target date] = ?PromptDate?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following expression:

```
if ([Example]='Business')
then([Date A])
else( [Date B])    
in_range ?p_date?
```

That being said,  I think the union approach maybe more controllable given [Example] may return different values.   For the Union approach you would have two queries

Query1 would have the filters Example= Business and Date A in_range ?p_date?
Query2 would have the filters Example <>Business and Date B in_range ?p_date?

Comment: When I do the union and try to add date prompt p_date doesn’t show up as a parameter to assign to date prompt

Comment: The only times I have seen prompts unavailable is when the report spec is invalid.

Comment: My bad:  I meant to say "parameters" not "prompts".